# PHP getting the strings "true" or "false" and converting them to 1 or 0

Tags: php, mysql

I am an Android developer and I'm working mostly with Java but as I'm developing my own primitive API in PHP, I'm struggling a bit here.

When a user adds a new item to their collection I have these three boolean values in the MySQL database:

- `item_is_gift`
- `item_condition_new`
- `item_bought_from_place`

In my Java code, I'm sending the string values of these - either `true` or `false`

When inserting them to MySQL I have to convert them to `1` or `0` accordingly, but I don't seem to be able to do so

Here is my code:

```
$item_is_gift           = $_POST['item_is_gift'];
$item_condition_new     = $_POST['item_condition_new'];
$item_bought_from_place = $_POST['item_bought_from_place'];

if($item_is_gift = true){
    $item_is_gift = 1;
} else {
    $item_is_gift = 0;
    $item_price = 0;
}

if($item_condition_new = true) {
    $item_condition_new = 1;
} else {
    $item_condition_new = 0;
}

if($item_bought_from_place = true) {
    $item_bought_from_place = 1;
    $item_bought_from_user = 0;
}
```

When I'm looking at the database records, all of these always say `1`.

Comment: You're using the `=` assignment operator where you should be using the `==` comparison operator. There's also the `===` comparison operator, though... but if the value you're expecting is a string `'true'`, then what you really need is `$var == 'true'`

Comment: you have to know than in php, non-empty strings (including `'true'` and `'false'` means true

Comment: @Asenar: Not always true... PHP has a really, really, _really_ messed up truth-table with loose comparisons `"0" == false` is true! [see the table here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're receiving a string value, being either *false* or *true*. To check use *the comparison operator*: `==`, not `=` (which is the assignment operator). And compare *strings*... you're comparing *a boolean* to a string:

```
if ($item_condition_new == 'true')
```

is what you're actually after. You should also check if the key in the `$_POST` array actually exists:

```
if (isset($_POST['item_condition_new']))
    $item_condition_new     = $_POST['item_condition_new'];
```

To avoid notices. Also process the input to be a tad more human-friendly: remove trailing/leading whitespace and accept both upper and lower-case chars:

```
$item_condition_new = trim($item_condition_new);//remove excess white-space
$item_condition_new = strtolower($item_condition_new);//make all lower-case
```

Then, you can do:

```
if ($item_condition_new == 'true')
{
    $item_condition_new = 1;
}
else
{
    $item_condition_new = 0;
}
```

A shorter way is using the ternary operator (but be careful with this!):

```
$item_condition_new = $item_condition_new == 'true' ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: thanks for reminding me to use ' ' around true, this was key. also thanks for the additional knowledge! out of the two best answers you were the first to answer via a comment so Im accepting this answer

Comment: @J.Kowalski: Thanks for acknowledging that comment :)... I hope you don't mind, just some friendly advice: please try to adopt/adhere to [the PHP-FIG coding standards](http://www.php-fig.org/)

Comment: hmm I thought my code looks clean enough, where have I gone wrong according to those standards (out of curiosity)?

Comment: @J.Kowalski: Nothing significant, just the spacing in your conditionals for example... Main reason for posting, though, is that I personally prefer camelCased varnames. They're more readable IMO. Mainly, I wanted to point out the existence of these conventions to people.

Comment: I also prefer camelCase and I use it in my java code, but when Im doing pho, I've had some PHP lessons and blokes were using underscores, so I thought maybe thats how they do it in PHP :) But I will switch to camelCase in the future! thanks

Answer (score 4):

Within your "if" you are setting a variable:

```
if($item_is_gift = true){
```

But what you want is to compare them. You would do this either with:

```
if($item_is_gift == true){
```

or with:

```
if($item_is_gift === true){
```

[The PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) has more info about the difference.

Furthermore you want to compare to a string. So you would have to write it like this:

```
if($item_is_gift == 'true'){
```

Comment: thanks, the quote thing was really important because it didnt work before I added it.

Answer (score 1):

Ah ha!

You're using "=" instead of "==".

Give that a go..

```
if($item_condition_new == true) {
    $item_condition_new = 1;
} else {
    $item_condition_new = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$item_is_gift = isset($_POST['item_is_gift']) && $_POST['item_is_gift'] == 'true'? 1 : 0;
// and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

You fail in the conditions of the if's. You are assigning instead of comparing...

```
if($item_is_gift == true){
...
if($item_condition_new == true) {
...
if($item_bought_from_place == true) {
```